# LDAP Querying users in an OU

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

In Elasticsearch I'm trying to make it's [user_search.filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/active-directory-realm.html) take users from a specified OU (not groups, just the users contained in this OU). It should work like a regular LDAP Query.

So far I've come up with the following:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=*)(OU=ES Users,OU=app_users,DC=app
    ,DC=domain,DC=com))
```

Unfortunately that does not return any results and I'm not sure why.

Comment: If you want to list all user entries with a dn built under the base "OU=ES Users,OU=app_users,DC=app,DC=domain,DC=com" just keep the filter as `(&(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=*))` and use `OU=ES Users,OU=app_users,DC=app,DC=domain,DC=com` as base dn. Otherwise do you mean all users that are *member of* a specific OU's group ? in that case the group name or dn should be provided (something like 'cn=someGroup,ou=ES Users,...,dc=com').

Comment: I've edited my question.How do you add the searchDN in the syntax? There's something I'm missing...

Comment: Did you try my suggestion ?

Comment: No as unfortunately unrelated to the syntax in Elasticsearch. However, I just noticed there's a "user_search.base_dn" variable there which might be what I was missing this entire time.

Comment: Ok I just realized it's for AD authentication in Elasticsearch, because it wasn't mentioned earlier. Where is your elasticsearch.yml ? Still the suggestion to set `OU=ES Users,OU=app_users,DC=app,DC=domain,DC=com` as base dn actually means in Elastic `user_search.base_dn = 'OU=ES Users,OU=app_users,DC=app,DC=domain,DC=com'`

Comment: You can put that in a new post and I'll accept it as answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to list all user entries with a dn built under the *base* "OU=ES Users" (as a container) you need to use `OU=ES Users,OU=app_users,DC=app,DC=domain,DC=com` as the search **base dn**.

For Active Directory user authentication in Elasticsearch, this means the following :

```
user_search.filter: (&(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=*))
user_search.base_dn: OU=ES Users,OU=app_users,DC=app,DC=domain,DC=com
```

See [Active Directory Realm Settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/active-directory-realm.html#ad-settings)

Answer (score 1):

A simple ldap request similar to:

```
ldapsearch -H ldaps://example.com:636 -x -D "cn=Admin" -W -b "ou=people,dc=example,dc=com" -s sub -a always -z 1000 "(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)" "objectClass"
```

Should work where the baseDN(="ou=people,dc=example,dc=com") is the OU you are looking to obtain the entries from within.